# Android record audio for piano application

Tags: android, audio, record

Hello everyone tell me please: for me it is very important to me to record sound from audio output stream or other but am need record hardware sound from speakers for my piano application. 
How do it work in other applications...
Please help me.﻿

Comment: What have you attempted so far? have you read through the api documentation? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: _"am need record hardware sound from speakers"_. Recording the audio going _to_ the speakers is not supported. Since your app is generating the audio you can implement mixing and encoding of the sounds in your app, so that you can write the result to a file at the same time as you play them.

Comment: And is it possible more detailed, I have 16 buttons and 16 sound pools on each of loaded a wav file as I play a certain melody  I can as both to record what I play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure you want to record piano from your android application or you you want to create a sound bank from a piano and use it in the app, but either way you can use **FMOD** http://www.fmod.org/download/

It is a very powerful audio library (lots of game engines using it e.g. CryEngine, Unity, ...), it has both abilities of recording and playback and gives you a cross-platform unified API.

However if you only want to create a piano audio bank, I believe using MIDI instruments would be a better idea

Comment: Big Thanks but, is it possible more detailed, I have 16 buttons and 16 sound pools on each of loaded a wav file as I play a certain melody I can as both to record what I play to wav file?
Read the Audio Output Stream and put bytes to wav file
I cant understand how it works on other applications
For Example: this app have 12 buttons with wav sound and record audio function
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paullipnyagov.drumpads24&hl=en

Comment: This is definitely possible using FMOD, you can simply set output to `FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER` or `OUTPUTMODE_WAVWRITER_NRT` for recording output, or you can use `DSP Mixer` to acheive both playback and record based on channel interactions. I highly recommend you to have a look at FMOD documents, there are lots of samples in their SDK

Comment: Please give me you Skype or Email. im do not understand how to record from FMOD but this is really important for me, my future will depend on this...